# How to use SED to find and replace URL strings with the "/" character in the targeted strings?

Tags: bash, sed, escaping

I'm attempting to use SED through OS X Terminal to perform a find and replace.

Imagine I have this string littered throughout the text file: http://www.find.com/page

And I want to replace it with this string: http://www.replace.com/page

I'm having trouble because I'm not sure how to properly escape or use the "/" character in my strings.  For example if I simply wanted to find "cat" and replace with "dog" I've found the following command that works perfectly:

```
sed -i '' 's/cat/dog/g' file.txt
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve the same functionality only instead of cat and dog have strings or URLs that container the "/" character?  I tried many different ways of escaping the "/" characters but then it seems as if SED can no longer "find" the string and it doesn't perform any find & replace actions.

Any help or tips are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 227, accepted):

`/` is not *the* delimiter in `sed` commands, it's just one of the possible ones. For this example, you can for example use `,` instead since it does not conflict with your strings;

```
echo 'I think http://www.find.com/page is my favorite' | 
    sed 's,http://www.find.com/page,http://www.replace.com/page,g'
```

Answer (score 52):

`sed` can take whatever follows the "s" as the separator. Since you are working with `URL` it is a good practice to use a different delimiter other than `/` to not confuse `sed` when your substitution ends and replacement begins.

However, having said that you can definitely use `/` if you wish too. You just need to escape the literal `/`.

So, you can either do:

```
sed 's/http:\/\/www.find.com\/page/http:\/\/www.replace.com\/page/g' input_file
```

or use a different delimiter to avoid making your cryptic sed more cryptic.

```
sed 's#http://www.find.com/page#http://www.replace.com/page#g' input_file
```

Comment: Using this approach, any reason why the following only outputs the file without any changes? `sed 's#:0.0.1#:new-build-number#g' some.yaml`. 1. The change does not occur. 2. I don't want the file printed, just updated.

Comment: The space character works well as a `sed` delimiter when processing URLs. It's visually clean and will never occur in a properly-formatted (i.e., escaped) URL.

Comment: I had to use `sed -i` to make it work. Why doesn't it work without the `-i`? I read that 
`-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
                 edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)`
What does it mean that it makes backup?