# Search and replace URL in all files

Tags: linux, shell, sed, text-processing

I'm looking to run script or command to mass change a string that is a URL.   I've viewed many examples on this forum, however none are working.

I have created a .sh file to run the following:

```
$SRC='$url = "https://www.myurl.com/subdir/process.do"';
$DST='$url="https://api.myurl.com/subdir/process.do"';
find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec sed -i 's/$SRC/$DST/g' {} +;
```

This is not working.   I'm thinking it may because of having backslashes in the search content?   The search/replace is needed to be run across all sub-directories on .php files.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SED to find and replace URL strings with the "/" character in the targeted strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16778667/608639) and [Use slashes in sed replace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5864146/608639).

Answer (score 1):

First thing - check your variable definitions. In bash, variable definitions usually do not start with a leading $. Ie, should be:

```
SRC='$url = "https://www.myurl.com/subdir/process.do"';
DST='$url="https://api.myurl.com/subdir/process.do"';
```

Next, you should switch to using single quotes for the pattern, and double quotes for the variable, as per:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/76808/how-do-i-use-variables-in-a-sed-command

Example that seems to work:

```
sed -i 's,'"$SRC"','"$DST"','
```

UPDATE:  This exact script works perfectly for me on Linux:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 SRC='$url = "https://www.myurl.com/subdir/process.do"'; 
 DST='$url="https://api.myurl.com/subdir/process.do"';
 find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec sed -i 's,'"$SRC"','"$DST"',' {} \;
```

Contents of file "asdf.php" created in home directory (before running script):

```
 $url = "https://www.myurl.com/subdir/process.do"
```

Contents of file "asdf.php" after running script:

```
 $url="https://api.myurl.com/subdir/process.do"
```

Comment: Your solution did not seem to work.  I also tried with removing the variables all together.
    find . -type f -name *.php -exec sed -i 's/'"https://www.myurl.com/subdir/process.do"'/'"https://api.myurl.com/subdir/process.do"'/g' {} +;

Comment: Try with commas and not slashes, ie:  find . -type f -name *.php -exec sed -i 's,'"yoururl"','"yournewurl"',' {} \;

Comment: That seems to help, but there are other errors happening.  

String found where operator expected at search.sh line 1, near "name '*.php'"
        (Do you need to predeclare name?)
String found where operator expected at name.sh line 1, near "i  's,"https://www.myurl.com/subdir/process.do","https://api.myurl.com/subdir/process.do",g'"
        (Do you need to predeclare i?)
syntax error at search.sh line 1, near "name '*.php'"